# Error Updating SSIS package to 2014 due to script component

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssdt, ssis-2014

I am trying to update a SSIS package that contains script component. The script component just gets the error description as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163.aspx).

I am using the update wizard in SSDT 2015 which should be compatible with SQL Server 2014. ([ssdt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx))

After the Package update wizard runs, I get a warning and information for every data flow that has a script component.

> Warning 0x40016044: Load table TableName: Found SQL Server
> Integration Services 2012 Script Component TableName Error
> Desc that requires migration!
>
> Information 0x4001601a: Load table TableName: The
> TableName Error Desc has been migrated. The package must be
> saved to retain migration changes

This looks to me like the script component has been migrated successfully. I then build and deploy the package to my SSIS instance.

When I try to execute the package on the instance, via SQL agent or Integration Services Catalog, the package fails verification with the following errors.

> Load table PersonDisability:Error:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException:
> The version of tablename Error Desc is not compatible with this
> version of the DataFlow.  [[The version or pipeline version or both
> for the specified component is higher than the current version.  This
> package was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component
> than is installed on the current PC.]]    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
> wrapper, Int32 lPipelineVersion)
>
> Load table TableName:Error: The component metadata for
> "TableName Error Desc" could not be upgraded to the newer
> version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

Based on these, if the messages are accurate, I have a version mismatch. My instance is 2014 SP1 CU3 (12.0.4427.24) and my SSDT that I did the package update with is 2015(14.0.51128.0)

Are these versions incompatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2010/VS 2012 => SQL Server 2012.

VS 2013 => SQL Server 2014.

VS 2015 => SQL Server 2016 (for now, soon they'll have the ability to target SQL Server 2012+)

So, you either need to redo your imports using SSDT for VS 2013/SQL Server 2014 or wait until they deliver the next release candidate for SQL Server which will have the ability to target specific releases of SSIS

Comment: The SSDT site states vs2015 supports 2014 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). I'll give it a try.

Comment: turns out VS2015 is only supported on SQL Server 2014 for the database tools. the BI tools are only preview and support 2016 only.

Comment: Once the final bits are minted, then VS 2015 will be able to author back versions of SSIS, until then [welcome to my world](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3tnpd.png)

Comment: Thx Bill, that was it.